# Concatenating columns from many sheets in a single sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to retrieve the data from many sheets into one single sheet.
I have 13 columns titles in my sheets, so I only take the data from the second row of all sheets.

For example, I have 3 sheets whose name are "FR", "UK", "DE", and "Master".
My columns are Country, Name, Month Usage, Model, Machine.
from Row 2, I have plenty of data for "FR","UK","DE".
"Master" has only the columns names.

What I want to merge all the data in a sheet called "Master".

So I took a code from Youtube "Combine one sheet into one" and the guy who has done the video made the code to retrieve data for 3 columns. 
It actually does retrieve data from my 3 columns.

```
function combineData() {

var masterSheet = "Master";

var ss = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(masterSheet);
var lc = ss.getLastColumn();
var lr = ss.getLastRow();

// ss.getRange(2,1,lr-1,lc).clearContent();
var labels = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, lc).getValues()[0];



labels.forEach(function(label, i) {
    var colValues = getCombinedColumnValues(label, masterSheet);
    ss.getRange(2, i + 1, colValues.length, 1).setValues(colValues);
})


function getCombinedColumnValues(label, masterSheetName) {

    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

    var colValues = [];

    for ([i, sheet] in sheets) {
        var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
        if (sheetName !== masterSheetName && sheetName !== "UID") {
            var tempValues = getColumnValues(label, sheetName);
            colValues = colValues.concat(tempValues);
        }
    }

    return colValues;
}

function getColumnValues(label, sheetName) {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var colIndex = getColumnIndex(label, sheetName);
    var numRows = ss.getLastRow() - 1;
    var colValues = ss.getRange(2, colIndex, numRows, 1).getValues(); // for name, index =2 but replacing by colIndex says "startong column too small)
    return colValues;
}


function getColumnIndex(label, sheetName) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

    var lc = ss.getLastColumn();
    var lookupRangeValues = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, lc).getValues()[0];

    var index = lookupRangeValues.indexOf(label) + 1;

    return index;
}
```

};

I thought the code was dynamic to the number of columns present in my Master sheet, but it isn't. My error while compiling is "The starting column of the range is too small"
Does anyone has an idea to fix the bug?

Thanks.

Comment: On which line do you have this error?

Comment: On :
labels.forEach(function(label, i) {
    var colValues = getCombinedColumnValues(label, masterSheet);
    ss.getRange(2, i + 1, colValues.length, 1).setValues(colValues);
})

I runned the debugger and I see that i = 3

Comment: But the error saying "The starting column of the range is too small." is right here:   var colValues = ss.getRange(2, colIndex, numRows, 1).getValues(); // for name, index =2 but replacing by colIndex says "startong column too small)

Comment: Use `Logger.log(colIndex)` to figure out what it's returning.

Comment: Logger.log(colIndex) gives values from 1 to 4.

Comment: Thank you all, I found my error, it wasn't the code. I didn't take all the columns names in my master sheet. There were 13 and in the others sheet 15, so it stopped the retrieve of data earlier!

Answer (score 1):

**Get Data from all Sheets**

```
function getDataFromAllSheets() {
  var excl=['Master'];//Sheets to exclude
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Master');//data destination
  sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();//clears old data but leaves headers
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++) {
    if(excl.indexOf(shts[i].getName())>-1) {//does not collected data from excluded sheets
      var vA=shts[i].getDataRange().getValues();//get sht[i] data
      for(var j=1;j<vA.length;j++) {//skips first line
        sh.appendRow(vA[j]);//appends all rows after first line
      }
    }
  }
}
```